# 11/8-type inequality from Heegaard Floer theory?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, 4-manifolds

Background: a well-known conjecture in $4$-dimensional topology states that if $M$ is a $4$-dimensional oriented closed spin smooth manifold, then the second Betti number of $M$ is bounded from below by $\frac{11}{8}$ times the absolute value of the signature of $M$. The most fundamental progress was made by [Furuta](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1839478), who used finite-dimensional approximations of the Seiberg-Witten equation and inputs from algebraic topology to derive inequalities of a similar type. There are follow-up works that sharpen or generalize Furuta's result. On the other hand, it is also known that Seiberg-Witten theory and Heegaard Floer theory more or less give the same output on the homological side.

Question: is it possible to prove Furuta's result using (a homotopical refinement of) invariants from Heegaard Floer theory?

Comment: Are you asking if we can prove something with a tool that doesn't exist and we wouldn't know what a homotopical refinement would even be?

Comment: It looks like we've already known how this tool would roughly look based on recent advances, and I also put "homotopical" in parenthesis in case it might cause confusion.